# break multiline events using LINE_BREAKER

Tags: splunk

for my multiline events delimited by line '------------', does not seem to work by setting LINE_BREAKER=^------------[\r\n]+ . Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this regex: `-{12}[\r\n]+`? I'm thinking using `^` might be looking for the start of the string, since this is a multiline event, instead of the start of the line. Also, using `{12}` notation will probably make your life easier